# Crypter Anti-Virus Test

Tags: cryptography

I have written a very simple/basic crypter in C++ and I would like to test it. How would I go about writing a simple MessageBox program that is "tainted" so that my Anti-virus will attempt to quarantine it upon running the file? Right now, I just have a MessageBox outputting "Hello".

I need a suspicious signature.

P.S. It is a runtime crypter. I worked on it after reading this white paper: 
http://www.exploit-db.com/wp-content/themes/exploit/docs/18849.pdf

Comment: Justin, is your crypter avilable somewhere? I would love to test it! Right now I'm using the Crypter from www.crypter.com , I'm satisfied with it but I would try a new one. To test it against your antivirus, just crypt a detected keylogger and see how's working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An idea would be to use the [EICAR string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file). This string was developed to test anti-virus. Try to make a program with that, see if it triggers your av and then apply your crypter.

Comment: Would something like this work?
http://pastebin.com/2JZp7LWd

I compiled it, and it outputs a text file with the EICAR string. The Antivirus did not assume it was a virus. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you run the AV on that file explicitly (like right-click "scan this file") or have you depended on the on-access scanner? In latter case the AV might just miss the access event. You should also check the AV whitelists: sometimes they whitelist files automatically based on some strange rules.

Comment: That was strange. Now the AV attempts to kill the file as it's being saved. Thank you.

Comment: As lucas suggested above you can try that method, you can also check out [Soft Crypter](http://www.softcrypter.com) google it, you can maybe use some of their ideas.

Comment: @user32779 Thanks. Why would I want to buy a crypter when I can code one myself? I will learn a lot more anyway.